# How to customise variations

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

how can I remove a specific variation selection.

My product has the option to add a canvas or no canvas, when I'm setting the variations for a product, I am unable to deselect the canvas option with the sizes. Is there any way I can only chose sizes without canvas variation?

Example: 
Product one:

canvas + Size

Size

Canvas + size + frame

frame + size

Is there any plugin, shortcode or somewhere i should look at, been trying to research it for 2 days haven't found anything.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you are asking - in the backend of each individual product - in the woocommerce Product Data section - under Variations - there should be a drop down menu at the top that says "Default Form Values"

You should be able to set that to "No Default"